# I am unable to disable a input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to disable a input field of return date when the travel type is one way. when I  checked the radio button for one way the return date is still enabled. Please help me what i am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap" 
    id="one_way">
    <span style="color:white;">One Way</span>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio"name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap"id="round_trip">
    <span style="color: white;">Round Trip</span>   
</label>

var button = document.getElementById('one_way');
if (document.getElementById('one_way').checked) {
   document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: please share your full code..

Comment: How and when is the JS code called?

Comment: What is datepicker1? Your code seems to be right, but if you want to disable the input field, you have to get the id `round_trip`, right?

Comment: There is two date section in my code one is datepicker  which for starting travel date and datepicker1 which is for return journey. I want to disable the return journey field when I select one way.

Comment: datepicker1 is for return journey date  code for datepicker1 is                                                             
<input type="text" name="" id="datepicker1" placeholder="Return Journey">             and code for datepicker is                                                                           
  <input type="text" name="" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date of Journey">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should must work! Use jQuery click event instead of Javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" />
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="travel_type" value="1"class="with-gap travel_type" 
        id="one_way">
        <span style="color:red;">One Way</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="travel_type" value="2"class="with-gap travel_type"id="round_trip">
        <span style="color: red;">Round Trip</span>   
    </label>
    </body>
    </html>
<script>
$(".travel_type").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1)
  {
    $("#datepicker1").prop('disabled', true); 
  }else{
    $("#datepicker1").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will use jQuery , it will be easy. I created this example using Jquery. Hope this will help you.

```js
$("input[name='travel_type']").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val()=='1'){
      $('#datepicker1').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
   $('#datepicker1').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>  One Way  
<input type="radio"  name="travel_type" value="1" class="with-gap" ></label>
<label>Round Trip
<input  type="radio" name="travel_type" value="2" class="with-gap" ></label>
<p><label>Date Picker <input type="date" name="datepicker" id="datepicker1"></label></p>
```

Comment: Its fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind events to radio buttons, Here is your working code,

```
var button = document.getElementById('one_way');
var button2 = document.getElementById('round_trip');
button.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (document.getElementById('one_way').checked) {
    document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = true;
  }
})

button2.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (!document.getElementById('one_way').checked) {
    document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = false;
  }
})
```

You can also check it on [JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/z17L0wqe/14/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call the "function" when radio button clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap" 
    id="one_way" onclick="functionRadioChecked();">
    <span style="color:red;">One Way</span>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio"name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap"id="round_trip">
    <span style="color: red;">Round Trip</span>   
</label>

<br><br><br>
<input type="date" id="datepicker1">

<script>
function functionRadioChecked() {
    var button = document.getElementById('one_way');
    if (document.getElementById('one_way').checked) {
        document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code disabled both date input fields datepicker for departure as well as datepicker1 for return

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code block where with self executing function on document load

```
    <html>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap" 
            id="one_way">
            <span style="color:black;">One Way</span>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio"name="travel_type"value=""class="with-gap"id="round_trip">
            <span style="color: black;">Round Trip</span>   
        </label>
        <script>
        (function() {
           var button1 = document.getElementById('one_way');
           button1.onclick = function()
           {            
           document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = true;
           }
           var button2 = document.getElementById('round_trip');
           button2.onclick = function()
           { 
           document.getElementById('datepicker1').disabled = false;
           }     
        })();
        </script>
    </html>
```

You could also assign a separate function to the radio button onclick
But depending your submitted code I would recommend the above code
Good Luck